# 2019 Mazda CX3 with start/stop engine, is a special "start stop" battery needed?

Tags: battery, mazda

I have a generic 60Ah battery in my car. It seems to work fine. Was installed by a kind of semi-shady shop, but has worked fine for over a year.

A more "reputable" shop looked at it and said "That battery is too small for this car."

The brand of battery is an Israeli brand, so I don't have perfect information on it. For example, I can't tell if it is a G35 size (and I am not sure I care if it fits in the battery well and is held down securely?).

- The battery is: Volta 34856093 / 60Ah / 420A-IEC / RC 100 Min
- [This is the page about the battery model](https://volta.co.il/volta_battery/tab-12-black-d23-12v-34856093/) (but the actual battery
  does not have recessed terminals the way this picture has, fwiw)

The car has no observable problem related to starting or running.

Should I take action or leave it alone?

(I notice it was installed without grease felts under the terminals, and some fur is starting to grow... I can solve that easily enough... a hazard of a penny pinching shop.)

Comment: What is the group size of the battery which was installed? According to what I see, it should be a 35 group size, with 650 CCA. What exactly is in there? If you could include the brand and model of what was installed, we might be able to tell you what's what.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 OP enhanced, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your owner's manual calls for a replacement battery of 60 Ah everywhere except Canada, where it calls for 65 Ah. So you're good.

Perhaps the reputable shop owner has a boat payment due . . . .

Comment: "Perhaps the reputable shop owner has a boat payment due . . . ." -- exactly what I am worried about..... g

Comment: @JonesomeReinstateMonica I have to give due credit for the "boat payment" quip to Tom & Ray Magliozzi, aka *Click & Clack*, mechanics who had a Boston-area call-in radio show called *Car Talk*. It was their way of explaining why a caller's mechanic did unnecessary work.

Comment: Click and Clack, aka the tappet brothers were a great source of not just automotive wisdom.

Comment: And to call a nationally broadcast program a Boston-area show does them a great disservice.

Comment: @JonCuster Well, OK, no disservice intended. Their broadcast went out live from 1977 - 1986 on WBUR as a local show for the Boston area only, then from 1986 -2012 as a nationally syndicated show on NPR, either live or time-shifted depending on the affiliate's location. After 2012 the show ran reruns on the NPR network through 2021. Old shows are still online as a podcast.

Comment: @MTA - the Space Shuttle episode alone was sufficient for their National Radio Hall of Fame induction, in my opinion... Still a classic.

Answer (score 0):

Vehicles with stop/start technology stress a car battery from repeated engine shutdowns and restarts as manufacturers try to eek out fuel mileage. Stop/start batteries have a bit more capacity for repeated starter use while driving since starting draws the most power from a battery and the alternator recharges it. Buying a battery from a repair shop means your battery is warranted by the shop that sold and installed the battery. There should be little difference between a regular battery from stop/start batteries but in the end, you won't know until the battery warranty ends, if it lasts that long. A big difference is between maintenance free batteries and older ones with caps to replenish cells with distilled water. Most batteries are sealed and maintenance free and better than older wet cell types. The 'fur' growing around battery terminals may be dried acid, vented and depositing around the area. A warm water solution with baking soda and toothbrush will dissolve dried battery acid with a plain water rinse. Bubbling is the reaction of neutralizing sulfuric acid. Don't let this solution get into the battery cells. Grease can be applied to terminals to delay future deposits.